# facebook like not unique

Tags: facebook, url, button, iframe, facebook-like

For some reason the like button on specific content pages is being grouped together, regardless of the URL in the FB Code being page specific.  Example one page shows 8.3k likes.

Here is the source showing the unique URL:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.oursite.com/ics-1-5ghz-snapdragon-video/&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px; margin-left:15px; float:right; width:78px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your og:url it's most likely overriding your plugin

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oursite.com"/>
```

to

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oursite.com/url/to/article"/>
```

Comment: Removed it entirely but still no change.

Comment: @fabreezy og:url is defined twice in your page. You can only define it once.

Comment: You are probably looking at a cached version of the page. When I'm logged in there's no cache and it's only defined once.

Comment: I dumped the cache and the issue is still happening for me.

Comment: @fabreezy http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mobilemag.com%2F2012%2F07%2F10%2Fmotorola-atrix-hd-announced-with-ics-1-5ghz-snapdragon-video%2F still there.

Comment: what an awesome tool.. that helped alot, thank you everything in order now.